# Modify xml values file using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm very new to python and I need to modify the

```
<test name="test02"></xmpp> to <test name="test03"></xmpp> 

<temp-config>QA</temp-config> to <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
```

for all 5 occurrences using python. 
Not sure what lib to use. Any help in this is really appreciated.

```
<config>
<logging></logging>
<test-mode>false</test-mode>
<test name="test02"></xmpp>
<mail></mail>
<test-system>0</test-system>
<system id="0" name="suite1" type="regression">
    <temp-config>QA</temp-config>
    <rpm>0.5</rpm>
    <cycles>3</cycles>
</system>
<system id="1" name="suite2" type="regression">
    <temp-config>QA</temp-config>
    <rpm>0.5</rpm>
    <cycles>3</cycles>
</system>
<system id="2" name="suite3" type="regression">
    <temp-config>QA</temp-config>
    <rpm>0.5</rpm>
    <cycles>3</cycles>
</system>
<system id="3" name="suite4" type="regression">
    <temp-config>QA</temp-config>
    <rpm>0.5</rpm>
    <cycles>3</cycles>
</system>
<system id="4" name="suite5" type="regression">
    <temp-config>QA</temp-config>
    <rpm>0.5</rpm>
    <cycles>3</cycles>
</system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de/). This example uses `lxml.etree`  and would actually fail on your example xml, as it has some unclosed tags in it. If you have the same problems with the real-world data that you are going to parse, use `lxml.html,` that can handle broken xml (*instructions added to the code as comments*).

```
In [14]: import lxml.etree as et  # for broken xml add an import:
                                  # import lxml.html as lh

In [15]: doc = et.fromstring(xmlstr)  # for broken xml replace this line with:
                                      # doc = lh.fromstring(xmlstr)

                                      # if you read xml from a file:
                                      # doc = et.parse('file_path')

In [16]: for elem in doc.xpath('.//temp-config'):
    ...:     elem.text = 'Prod'
    ...:     

In [17]: print et.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
<config>
  <logging/>
  <test-mode>false</test-mode>
  <test name="test02">
    <mail/>
    <test-system>0</test-system>
    <system id="0" name="suite1" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
    <system id="1" name="suite2" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
    <system id="2" name="suite3" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
    <system id="3" name="suite4" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
    <system id="4" name="suite5" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
  </test>
</config>
```

**Note:** As pointed out by others, you have some less powerful alternatives in the standard library. For simple tasks as this they may be well suited, however, *if your xml files are broken*, parsing them with standard library tools equals wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

`ElementTree` is a great choice -- pure Python and included in the standard library, so it's the most portable option.  However, I always go straight to `lxml` -- it has the same API, it's just faster and it can do a lot more (since it is effectively a wrapper around `libxml2`).

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(path_to_my_xml)

for elem in tree.findall('.//test'):
    assert elem.attrib['name'] == 'test02'
    elem.attrib['name'] == 'test03'

for elem in tree.findall('.//temp-config'):
    assert elem.text == 'QA'
    elem.text = 'Prod'

with open(path_to_output_file, 'w') as file_handle:
    file_handle.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf8'))
```

Comment: Sorry I get the following error:                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testrun.py", line 13, in <module>
    with open(tree, 'w') as file_handle:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, lxml.etree._ElementTree found

Comment: @DigitalDyn - `with open(tree, 'w') as file_handle:` is not part of what I posted.  i think you may have made a copy-and-paste error :)

Comment: @DigitalDyn `with open(file_out, 'wb') as file_handle:`

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use ElementTree: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

example:

```
for atype in e.findall('type')
 print(atype.get('foobar'))
```

or see this thread: [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/easiest-way-to-parse-xml-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answers above, using lxml, here's how you'd change the 'name' attribute value:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(path_to_my_xml)
for elem in tree.xpath('.//temp-config'):
    elem.text = 'Prod'
for elem in tree.xpath(".//test[@name='test02']"):
    elem.attrib['name'] = 'test03'
```